# MSSQL - For Each Table, export as CSV

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, csv

In MSSQL/Studio Management, I have a large database with about 80 tables. I'd like to export each table in to it's own CSV with | as the delimiter, but I don't want to have to go one by one in Studio to do it. Is there a form of command line that can pull it off for me? I'm experienced in Python if there's an answer there, but I'd like anything at this rate as I plan on moving the tables to be used elsewhere.

Any help is brilliant, thanks.

Comment: you can use `sp_foreachtable` it is undocummented. but there is plenty of examples on the web. If you combine that with `BCP` command, you should be able to achieve it.

Comment: Right Click your database --> Tasks --> Export/Export Data, there you can select all or tables you want to export to CSV file